# select('*') with group_by in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter. My problem is i want to show all rows having same id. But when i perform group_by it only outputs one row of that group.

below is my model

```
function category_content(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('category');
        $this->db->group_by('category_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: instead of group use order by id

Comment: use order by and if you want to get records of specific id then use where clause group by is use when you want to group identical rows.

Answer (score 1):

As per the sql properties `Group By` groups all the matching records and will show you only one. It seems you want to sort them by id. Then its better to use `order by`

Answer (score 0):

See the Example hope you will get to know this..

```
    tableA
    _____
    id  name    marks
    --  ----    ---
    1   x       25
    2   y       27
    1   z       30


    SELECT * FROM tableA group by id

OUTPUT:
1   x   25
2   y   27
```

in your case you should use WHERE clause.

```
    SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id=1

OUTPUT:
1   x   25
1   z   30


    function category_content(){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('category');
            $this->db->where($category_id);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }
```

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html](http://Group%20By%20:%20MYSQL)